# Functional CLT proof Theorem 7.4.1 on page 354-355 of Ethier and Kurtz 1986

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, markov-process, stochastic-integrals

In the proof of the FCLT Theorem 7.4.1 of Ethier and Kurtz (1986) "Markov Processes", the last four lines on p.355 write ($\tau_n^r = \inf\{t: |X_n(t)|\geq r\}$):

"Consequently, if $X$ is a solution of the martingale problem for $(A, v)$, then $X(\cdot\wedge\tau_n^r)\Rightarrow X(\cdot\wedge\tau^r)$ for all $r$ such that $P\{lim_{s\to r} \tau^s = \tau^r\} = 1$ (here
$\tau^r = \inf\{t: |X(t)|\geq r\}$). But $\tau_r\to \infty$ as $r\to\infty$ (since $X$ has sample paths in $C_{\mathbb R^d}[0,\infty)$), so $X_n\Rightarrow X$."

I understand why $X_n(\cdot\wedge\tau_n^r)\Rightarrow X(\cdot\wedge\tau^r)$ from the earlier development of the proof, but there is a gap between this and the desired weak convergence $X_n\Rightarrow X$.

**My thoughts to fill this gap:** since we already have $X(\cdot\wedge\tau_n^r)\Rightarrow X(\cdot\wedge\tau^r)$, the proof of $X_n\Rightarrow X$ is complete by Corollary 3.3.3 on p.110 of EK86 if we show

1. $d\big(X_n,X_n(\cdot\wedge\tau_n^r)\big)\stackrel{p}{\to}0$ as $n,r\to\infty$
2. $d\big(X(\cdot\wedge\tau^r),X\big)\stackrel{p}{\to}0$ as $r\to\infty$

where $d(x,y)=\sum_{j=1}^d d_{\infty}(x_j,y_j)$ is the product Skorohod metric of $D_{\mathbb R^d}[0,\infty)$ where $d_{\infty}(x_j,y_j)$ is defined as Eq. (5.2) on p.117 of EK86.

Based on a previous post ([Martingale central limit theorem proof on p.341 of Ethier and Kurtz (1986)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2406985/martingale-central-limit-theorem-proof-on-p-341-of-ethier-and-kurtz-1986)), we can estimate (WLOG, set dimension $d=1$):
$$
d(X_n,X_n(\cdot\wedge\tau_n^r)) \leq e^{-\tau_n^r}
$$
and
$$
d(X(\cdot\wedge\tau^r),X) \leq e^{-\tau^r}.
$$
The proof for (2) can be finished by using the the second estimation together with the fact $\tau_r\to \infty$ as $r\to\infty$ a.s.

**Question:** The problem is (1). I am not sure how to show $\tau_n^r\stackrel{p}{\to}\infty$ as $r,n\to\infty$. A fact may be relevant: $\tau_n^r\Rightarrow\tau^r$ for *all but countably many $r$* noted on the 5th line on page 355. Is this enough for our purpose? Don't we need process convergence of $\tau_n^r\Rightarrow\tau^r$ in $r$ to complete the job? (But the stopping time is not a continuous mapping in the topology generated by $d(x,y)$ by Whitt (1980))

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

After some thoughts, I found that showing (1) is actually not hard. I provide some details here.

Recall that $X_n(\cdot\wedge\tau_n^r)\Rightarrow X(\cdot\wedge\tau^r)$ in $D_{\mathbb R^d}[0,\infty)$ for all but countably many $r$ (pointwisely for each of them), if $T<\tau_n^r$, we have $X_n \Rightarrow X$ in $D_{\mathbb R^d}[0,T]$, and by continuous mapping theorem we also have

$$
\sup_{t\leq T}\|X_n(t)\|_2 \Rightarrow \sup_{t\leq T}\|X(t)\|_2 \quad\mbox{as }n\to\infty,
$$
where $\sup_{t\leq T}\|X(t)\|_2$ is a continuous random variable (r.v.) because $X(t)$ is a Gaussian process with a.s. continuous sample path.

Therefore, for any $T>0$, for all but countably many $r$ that $X_n(\cdot\wedge\tau_n^r)\Rightarrow X(\cdot\wedge\tau^r)$ in $D_{\mathbb R^d}[0,\infty)$,
$$
P(\tau_n^r>T)=P\big(\sup_{0 \leq t\leq T}\|X_n(t)\|_2<r\big) = P\big(\sup_{0 \leq t\leq T}\|X(t)\|_2<r\big) + R_n(r)
$$

where $R_n(r) = P(\sup_{t\leq T}\|X_n(t)\|_2<r)-P(\sup_{t\leq T}\|X_n(t)\|_2<r)$ satisfies $\sup_{r\in\mathbb R_+}|R_n(r)|=o(1)$ as $n\to\infty$ because the convergence in distribution to continuous r.v. implies uniform convergence of CDFs ([Convergence in law implies uniform convergence of cdf's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1670030/convergence-in-law-implies-uniform-convergence-of-cdfs)).

As $n\to\infty$ and $r\to\infty$ along an increasing countable sequence, since $R_n=o(1)$ uniformly in $r$, we obtain that $P(\tau_n^r>T)\to 1$ (since $P(\sup_{0 \leq t\leq T}\|X(t)\|_2<r)\to 1$ as $r\to\infty$ along an increasing countable sequence) for any $T>0$. This verifies that $\tau_n^r\stackrel{p}{\to}\infty$ as $r$ and $n$ $\to\infty$.